# incompatibility issues with package{biblatex} and package{chapterbib} ,, Unable to generate pdf

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, overleaf

I am using a template for my thesis in overleaf and I've been trying to have a seprate bibliography after each chapter using this

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{library}
```

All the packages are listed below, I know package{biblatex} and package{chapterbib} are not compatible. but everytime I comment biblatex the pdf won't be generatd!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}

 
%PhD Thesis Template

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{longtable,tabu}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{clrscode}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos} 
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage[draft=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{200mm} 
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{100mm} 
\textblockorigin{61mm}{19mm}


\title{The Thesis Title \\will go here when you know it: \\a meaningful and succinct phrase}
\author{Your Name Here \\
\\
PhD thesis\\
\\


\date{2016}
   
\include{abstract}  

\setcounter{page}{3}

\include{acknowledgements}

\include{license}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\include{zabbreviations}

\include{intro}

\include{background}


\include{conclusions}

\appendix



\end{document}
```

in Intro chapter code will be like

```
\chapter{Introduction}
\label{ch:intro}

text
and then
%% set the bib style
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{library}
```

I would really apreciate any help

Comment: Can you please extend your example do something others can work with without having to add anything. I would assume that `biblatex` can do something similar to `chapterbib` out of the box.

Comment: Thanks .. I completed the example

Comment: Don't use natbib and chapterbib with biblatex. They are not compatible. And better don't use the tabu package, it is broken and unmaintained.

Comment: somehow it workrd now! I just  commented the biblatex package %\usepackage{biblatex},, When I did that before pdf won't generated ! thanks both

Answer (score 1):

You are loading several bibliography/citation-related packages, namely

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
```

You even load `natbib` twice (it is generally recommended to load packages only once as that avoids option clashes and is less confusing for humans reading the code as well).

`biblatex` is incompatible with the `thebibliography`/BibTeX-based approach needed for `natbib` and `chapterbib`. You cannot load these three packages together.

Since you generate your bibliography with the BibTeX-based approach

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{library}
```

I suggest you get rid of `biblatex`. Delete the line

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
```

For good measure you may want to delete the `.aux` file and `.bbl` before you recompile (delete the Cache in Overleaf https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Clearing_the_cache).

Refer to [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864) for a bit of background reading on the whole BibTeX/`natbib` vs `biblatex` distinction.